# Segment audience by organic impressions or page likes in Facebook analytics

Tags: facebook-analytics

I'm currently using Facebook Analytics to see the activity on a mobile game. I'm able to segment my game users in a number of different ways directly related to Facebook, i.e. Facebook logins in a certain time period etc. However, I would really like to be able to segment the audience by organic Facebook impressions and page likes. For example:

- A segment of people who have the game installed AND like the game's page on Facebook
- A segment of people who have seen one of the game's Facebook page organic posts, AND have launched/installed the game

The idea is that I would like to get a better insight of how our organic Facebook actions are affecting user events. If this isn't possible on Facebook analytics, does anyone have any idea of a platform where it is?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 1:**
As of now it doesn't appear that you are able to add the Event of a "Page Like" as a parameter for a Segment against a FB Page. FB Page analytics is still listed as beta [here](https://www.intern.facebook.com/help/analytics/988839004513275?helpref=faq_content). It's not an Event currently available. List of Page Events [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/page-analytics).

**Alternative Answer to Question 2:**
As of now you are not able to Segment people by impressions within FBA. You can however create a Segment based on facebook's [definition](https://www.intern.facebook.com/help/analytics/1609433782661192?helpref=faq_content) of Facebook Organic App Install Source.

> ***Facebook Organic:*** Installs from a shared non-ad link on Facebook (including Pages).

To do this, you need to apply the following Segment:

> **Apply the segment:** Condition -> "*App Install Source*" App Install Source -> "*is*" -> "*Facebook Organic*"